# Django model and before Christ DateField

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, model, datefield

I would like to create a field for a date that spans from B.C. and A.D. dates. I think that a simple DateField would not be enough. How can I represent a date like this one: 200 b.C. ?

Comment: I don't think it is supported in a date field, see [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24955). You'll have to implement something on your own. Cheers.

Comment: thanks for answer.